# using Scrapy for crawling ajax pages

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

i am using Scrapy for a month. I am able to crawl and scrape several websites(infact i have crawled 900 websites) based on keywords given in pipelines.Now , the problem is when we come across javapages (ajax), scrapy doesnt scrape. I am trying to use following code [selenium code for scraping ajax pages using scrapy](http://snipplr.com/view/66998/rendered-javascript-crawler-with-scrapy-and-selenium-rc/) and make suitable changes to scrape ajax pages

Do u guys have any good idea for scraping javapages using scrapy

second problem , i face is scrapy doesnt scrape login page

Comment: Could you be more specific on what problems do you have with scraping login page? Provide the code and the url you are using.

Comment: @ alecxe . this is my spider code http://notepad.cc/huxido16

Comment: https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapyjs

Comment: @StevenAlmeroth. i am trying using download middleware setup, but i get a error at **import gtk **.  error:    from glib._glib import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be foun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First monitor the Request that has been sent using ajax (use fiddler for this purpose or firefox firebug), then make similar Request in scrapy and it will bring the response.

and i cant understand what do u mean by "scrapy doesnt scrape login page":
does it mean that u cant scrap pages that requires u to be logged in or the login page itself

Comment: ""scrapy doesnt scrape login page"".i mean to say login page itself.   thanks

Comment: first of all  thanks for ur reply. I am using firebug to monitor and to note xpath(request sent using ajax ).should i use the same xpath in my scrpay project .

Comment: Yes u can use the same xpath in your scrapy project!

Comment: May i know if you have any idea on how to scrape login pageitsef

Comment: well, i have not faced any problem ever in scraping a login page, but for your case(in which you are trying to scrape yahoo login page) first go to http://www.yahoo.com(give this as start url) then using xpath get the url of the signin page make request on that url and it will be available . This should work

Comment: i have tried that... but no luck

Comment: @omair_77 I have link of ajax call but I don't knwo how to make a similar call using scrapy. please provide a code example how to so it.